# What is a good way to model this?

Tags: classification, predictive-modeling, ensemble-modeling

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like this :

| user | Date | TP_A | TP_C | TP_D | TP_E | TP_B | TP_F | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 11-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 15-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 17-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 18-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 25-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 26-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 05-08-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 12-08-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 04-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 05-07-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 01-11-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 09-11-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 20-11-2014 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I need to predict if a user's Order(target) will get executed or not and top N users whose orders are likely to get executed, based on the above training set (sample) which contains columns user_id,Date and Touch Points .
Should I consider the Date to build the classification, if so how can I process the dates. The predict set has same columns but for a diferent future timeframe .

Comment: What kind of order is this ? Is there limit on number of orders in a day ? What are touch points?

Comment: yes only one order execution per `Date` per user.An user can however have multiple order executions across various timeframes.You can think of touch points as actions by user, like submit form, click on link,view image.order execution(target)  as purchase

Comment: One thing more . Why some orders get executed and some not ? Which industry data it is ?

Comment: you can imagine a case of purchasing on a web app. Order execution can be treated as a buy

Comment: I can give some tips. Feature engineering on date is required like number of active days in past 10 days , whether day is weekend. Another variable you can consider is percentage of successful order in past

Comment: yes I though so. But predict set dates(year) are different from train set year. I am confused on two points a.) if we should consider Date b.) If we should , what way we can use it. I dont think visit count can help.

Comment: We are capturing weekend , number of active days . These are independent of year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138482/discussion-between-scope-and-amol-goel).